# Unmap Control t in ideavimrc

Tags: ideavim

I'm sure this is an awfully simple question but I'm just trying to unmap control + t from vim so I can use the default shortcut for renaming in intelliJ. Can anyone help me out?

So for I've tried adding a variety of things like

```
:unmap <C-T>
```

but with no success. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things you can try.

1. Add the following line to .ideavimrc

```
unmap <C-t>
```

Note that the "t" is lower case. Once you've added this line, hit the reload button.

[image]

2. In Android Studio and other IntelliJ products, there is a settings tab for Vim (Settings -> Editor -> Vim). Here you can tell IntelliJ what commands are reserved for the IDE and which are for Vim.

[image]

Comment: I actually figured it out but forgot to post it here! The second one worked for me—going into the Vim settings in the editor. I'll accept your answer as correct